# How to filter by item in many to many field?

Tags: python, django-models

So I have this Cass_school model in which i have the many to many students field. What I want to do is to find the Class_school where request.user is in students. Any ideas?

```
class User(AbstractUser):
username = None
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
email = models.EmailField(('email address'), unique=True)
role = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False)
child = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="parent", blank=True, null=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'role')

class Class_school(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
principal_teacher = models.ForeignKey("User", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="class_teacher")
students = models.ManyToManyField("User", related_name="class_students")
```

Also does anybody know if I can put an attribute to the students field so that a user can t be in two or more classes? Thank you!

UPDATE:
The python code below is used to get the subjects where origin-class is a foreign key for Class_school in order to get all of the subjects o f the class where the user in I need to get the Class_school first:

```
def classes_view(request):
schclass = Class_school.objects.filter(students=request.user)
subjects = Subject.objects.filter(origin_class=schclass)
subjects = subjects.order_by('title').all()
return render(request, "eduon/index.html", {
    'subjects': subjects,
})
```

Comment: Please share your `User` model.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter with:

```
Class_school.objects.filter(students=request.user)
```

Django will make a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and filter the records where `request.user` appears at the joined `students` relation.

There can be multiple of such `Class_school`s, since in a `ManyToManyField`, the same `User` can be a member of multiple `Class_school`s.

You can however *not* `.filter(…)` *directly* with this `QuerySet`, since it is a *collection* of `Class_school`s, not a single one. You can filter on the related object:

```
def classes_view(request):
    subjects = Subject.objects.filter(
        origin_class__students=request.user
    ).order_by('title')
    return render(request, 'eduon/index.html', {
        'subjects': subjects,
    })
```

or use an [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
def classes_view(request):
    schclass = Class_school.objects.filter(students=request.user)
    subjects = Subject.objects.filter(
        origin_class__in=schclass
    ).order_by('title')
    return render(request, 'eduon/index.html', {
        'subjects': subjects,
    })
```

---

> **Note**: Models in Django are written in *PerlCase*, not *snake_case*,
> so you might want to rename the model from <s>`Class_school`</s> to `ClassSchool`.

Comment: does't work because students is a many to many field, I want to check if request.user is in students

Comment: @Radal: did you test this? The fact that it is a many-to-many field does not mean you can not filter on it like that.

Comment: 'The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.' this is the error

Comment: @Radal: you likely use another `User` model, and used `.filter(..)` instead of `.get(..)` in the view to get the custom user model. Can you share the custom user model? `request.user` is a *single* object. If you use `MyUser.objects.filter(..)` then that is a *collection* of `MyUser`s, so you can not use that.

Comment: sure, i ve added now

Comment: @Radal: but do you use `request.user` at the filter part? The error message indicates that you use a `QuerySet`, not `request.user`.

Comment: this is the code i've used to filter, yet it did not work: schclass = Class_school.objects.filter(students=request.user)

Comment: and request.user is like the logged user

Comment: @Radal: did you use the *result* in another `QuerySet`? Exactly where in the view does it error?

Comment: at the beginning of a function used for a page of my site

Comment: @Radal: yes, but the exact location is of importance. Based on the error message, it looks like you use the *result* of this query somewhere, like `.filter(school=classschool)`, but that does not make sense, since as said, `classschool`, the outcome of the query, is a `QuerySet`, a *collection* of objects, if you want to filter, you can use the `__in` lookup, but even better is to this in a single `QuerySet`.

Comment: @Radal: can you include the view, and specify where it goes wrong in the view function.

Comment: @Radal: the problem was in the `Subject.objects.filter(..)` part. See edit.

Comment: so i tried both of them but now i keep getting this error: "Reverse for 'class' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['class/(?P<class_id>[0-9]+)$']" I just don t know what to do...

Comment: @Radal: but that is in the *template*, you use a `{% url ... bla %}`, but `bla` is not a valid expresion. If you use `DEBUG=True`, normally the response will show the exact location where this template tag is located.